# Check a given date is within a varchar date list

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

There is a list of dates stored in a table like this. In the Dates column, it calculates and stores the dates between FromDate and ToDate.

[image]

I have created a function to merge all the dates and it returns the list of dates as a varchar value like this.

[image]

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(MAX)

Select @s=COALESCE(@s + ',','')+LeaveDates
from LeaveRequest where EmpId=1154  
and Date >= DATEADD(month, -5, GETDATE())

IF '10-03-2017' in (@s) 
print 'Yes'
else 
print 'No'
print @s
```

**Result**

No

'19-10-2016','08-03-2017', '09-03-2017', '10-03-2017', '11-03-2017'

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(MAX)

Select @s=COALESCE(@s + ',','')+LeaveDates
from LeaveRequest where EmpId=1154  
and Date >= DATEADD(month, -5, GETDATE())

IF '10-03-2017' in ('19-10-2016','08-03-2017', '09-03-2017', '10-03-2017', '11-03-2017') 
print 'Yes'
else 
print 'No'
print @s
```

**Result**

Yes

'19-10-2016','08-03-2017', '09-03-2017', '10-03-2017', '11-03-2017'

It doesn't give the required result with that function.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to check if date is between FromDate and ToDate?

Comment: How to write the query? I couldn't find a way..that's why I tried like this..

Comment: what result do you need?

Comment: Assume the given date is '10-03-2017' and it is within the date list. Then it should return a value as 'Yes' . If the given date is  '12-03-2017'  it should return a value as 'No'.

Comment: If you want to check a date between FromDate and ToDate you can try this: `WHERE DATE BETWEEN FromDate and ToDate`

Comment: Ohh..it is working...I can't imagine why I'm taking things this much complicated..

Comment: Just for an answer to the question. I have added it as answer as well. If it worked out you can select it as answer as well. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :-

If you want to check a date between `FromDate` and `ToDate` you can try this:

```
 WHERE DATE BETWEEN FromDate and ToDate
```